# SqlFunctions.DateAdd equivalent in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am converting a project to .Net Core and am looking for an equivalent parse operation for a string to SQL in EF core to be used as a predicate (DateAdd).

```
items.Where(x => SqlFunctions.DateAdd("day", 0, x.ToDateString) <= toDate)
```

No luck in EF.Functions. Is there an equivalent?

Cheers

KH

Answer (score 3):

Use .NET code instead.

```
items.Where(x => x.ToDateString.AddDays(0) <= toDate)
```

**EDITED for checking 200,000 records performance**

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I have over 100,000 items and a reasonably involved object graph so would prefer to defer this logic to SQL to trim the dataset.

Comment: Edited post.You can check screenshot. I have 200,000 items and still faster. 0.08ms without filter and 0.55ms with filter. 0.55ms is like 0.0005 sec. still not faster for you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for updated answer but this is not equivalent to SqlFunctions.DateAdd as it executes in a different process. There is a noticeable speed different between the two using my model as its very complex so I need to execute this in SQL. Thanks again.

Comment: The AddDays-Expression IS translated to SQL. Anything that cannot be tranlsated, EF Core will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your equation and use

```
EF.Functions.DateDiffDay(x.ToDateString - toDate) <= 0
```